# Clean and Reusable Exception Handling in Django and DRF (Pythonic problem)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm working on a **Django API** project and I'm facing a challenge with exception handling. Specifically, I want to handle specific exceptions raised in my business logic and map them to corresponding Django REST framework (DRF) exceptions in a clean and reusable way.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
# My business logic
class UserBusinessLogicLayer(Manager):
    """
    This is the business logic layer for User management.
    """
    def get_user_with_identifier(self, identifier: str, allow_username: bool = True) -> "User":
        # ... (omitting some code for brevity)

        user = self.filter(reduce(operator.or_, conditions)).first()

        if not user:
            raise self.model.DoesNotExist("User Does not exist.")

        if not user.is_active:
            logger.info(
                "The user with username/email/phone-number %s is not active",
                identifier,
                exc_info=True,
            )
            raise DeactivatedUser(
                f"This account has been deactivated since {user.status_change}", user
            )

        if not user.is_email_verified:
            logger.info(
                "The user %s hasn't verified the email",
                identifier,
                exc_info=True,
            )
            raise NotVerifiedEmail("This account hasn't verified the its email")

        return user
```

and this is how i use the code:

```
try:
    user = User.bll.get_user_with_identifier(identifier, allow_username=False)

except User.DoesNotExist as error:
    # this is how i normally handle the exceptions
    logger.info(
        "there is no user with username/email/phone-number %s",
        identifier,
        exc_info=True,
    )
    raise exceptions.NotFound("Invalid input.") from error # this is api exception

except Exception as error:
    # But I want to map my business logic exceptions to DRF exceptions
    # and raise them to be handled in my API views
    # Without repeating this code in every view
```

What's the best approach to achieve this?

Comment: You [can configure a custom exception handler](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#custom-exception-handling).

Comment: @AKX first I'm using `drf-standardized-errors` for better responses, and its doing it really weird and don't really want to touch that, So I would rather to do another kind of exceptions mapping so even if its not drf and some other exceptions related to other services, still use the same method. also need to do some sort of logging for each exception as you can see in the code